# java - how do you make a resourceloader?

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, resources, loader

After I export my eclipse java project that has audio in it, and I run the jar file none of the sounds work even after I check that the files are in the jar. All the sounds work when I build it in Eclipse but never after I export it. After doing some research I think I need something called a ResourceLoader but I cant find and tutorials for it. Could someone tell me how to do this? or tell me a better way to fix the problem?

Comment: Please show the code loading the sound files.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html check for the usage of getResource and getresourceAsStream methods.

EG:

```
InputStream audio = new BufferedInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("audio/bing.au"));
```

Comment: this is not helping me at all. I dont understand what im even supposed to do. Please explain more..

Comment: The idea of the resource loader is to get data from the application jar - as you have described in your problem statement. If the audio files are embedded in jar the normal operations on File class are not usable hence you have to bypass them via the code above. Let us know more about your code in order to help.