# I can't load a file for a JUnit test in Maven

Tags: maven, resources, junit4, surefire

I know there's a lot of questions and answers about this, but I've tried everything I've read and you can be sure it has been a lot.
I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3.1.0 (but without Spring yet), embedded Maven 3.0.4 and JUnit 4. Ubuntu 12.04.
I have this JUnit 4 test:

```
    @Test
public final void testCheckAudio() {
    final InputStream stream = AudioServiceImplTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.wav");
    assertNotNull(stream);
}
```

test.wav is in src/test/resources and I've checked it's copied to target/test-classes.
When I do Run as ... Maven Test I got:
...
Failed tests:   testCheckAudio(edu.gerher.askitcollector.test.services.AudioServiceImplTest)
...
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project ...

---

### Test set: MyPackage.AudioServiceImplTest

Tests run: 16, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.039 sec <<< FAILURE!
testCheckAudio(MyPackage.AudioServiceImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
    at edu.gerher.askitcollector.test.services.AudioServiceImplTest.testCheckAudio(AudioServiceImplTest.java:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)

I've tried with "test.wav", "/test.wav", creating the test package in src/test/resources and copying also the file there and trying "/MyPackage/test.wav", "MyPackage/test.wav". Always the same answer. It can't find the file.

I've tried Run as... JUnit Test and the same asnwers.
En el pom.xml I have

```
<build>
...
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>.../src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>.../src/test/resources</directory>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
<directory>.../target</directory>
```

Really, thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Can you post output of maven execution with `-X` command line option?

Comment: Why have you changed the maven defaults to such strange things? What's the reason for that ? Show the complete pom file? Or are these definitions just repeating the defaults ?

Comment: Default values. ... means the project directory.

Comment: Do you really need all the output? It's about 777 lines. I don't mind to post it but...

Comment: Use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/srbi8Agh

Comment: Ok, can you try to put full path to wav file and see if it works? According to the debug output everything should be working fine.

Comment: Well. "/to/my/project/target/test-classes/test.wav" fail. "to/my/project/target/test-classes/test.wav" fail as well. But File file = new File("target/test-classes/test.wav") is OK and File file = new File("/target/test-classes/test.wav") is OK too. So, I know this isn't the best way, but it's the only way I have. I'd like to give the thanks to everybody that has help me to get the solution, specially to Andrey Logvinov. Can I give you any "+1" or something like this? (Sorry, it's my first question and I'm a bit lost)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is still relevant but:
Assume you have an image under src/test/resources/tree.png. With the standard maven settings you can reference it in the code like this:

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/test/resources/tree.png"));
```

This is relative to the current project location.

If you package your project in a jar file and want to use the resources in the running code, you should also look at Java ResourceLoader. Here is a starting point: [java - how do you make a resourceloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868223/java-how-do-you-make-a-resourceloader)

Answer (score 0):

Why have you changed the Maven defaults for resource locations? What should "..." point to?

My suggestion:
1. remove the custom resources configuration
2. put the desired file in src/test/resources
3. reference it with getResourceAsStream("/test.wav");

Comment: 1. NO custom resources configuration (... is an abreviation for my project directory) 2. My files are in src/test/resources 3. I've tried with "test.wav", "/test.wav" and many other combinations with the same result. Nothing

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I need to read image files from src/test/resource/WsqImages

```
  File filepath= new File("src" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator
    + "resources" + File.separator + "WSQImages");

    try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
        filepath))) {

    Bitmap bitmap = WSQJavaUtil.getBitMap(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
    assertNotNull("BitMap Creation faild", bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    throw new WSQDecompressionException(e.getMessage(), e);

    }
```